# How to test react-router-dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

### Problem

I have read https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/guides/testing.md

I want to test `react-router-dom`, I don't care about how it work, I just need to make sure the library is working into my project boilerplate.

### Reproduction

I am testing this component

```
    <Link to="/toto">
      toto
    </Link>
```

This is the test

```
  it('it expands when the button is clicked', () => {
    const renderedComponent = mount(<Wrapper>
      <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/']}>
        <Demo />
      </MemoryRouter>
    </Wrapper>);
    renderedComponent.find('a').simulate('click');
    expect(location.pathname).toBe('toto');
  });
```

### Expected

to be `true`

### Result

`blank`

### Question

How can I test `react-router-dom`?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the code for `Link`, you see this code:

```
handleClick = event => {
    if (this.props.onClick) this.props.onClick(event);

    if (
      !event.defaultPrevented && // onClick prevented default
      event.button === 0 && // ignore everything but left clicks
      !this.props.target && // let browser handle "target=_blank" etc.
      !isModifiedEvent(event) // ignore clicks with modifier keys
    ) {
      event.preventDefault();

      const { history } = this.context.router;
      const { replace, to } = this.props;

      if (replace) {
        history.replace(to);
      } else {
        history.push(to);
      }
    }
  };
```

So, presumably you find `Link` instead of `a` and override this method to return a value to your own callback you can validate the path set on the `<Link>`, This doesn't directly test `react-router` but it will validate that the paths you have set in your link are correct which is what your tests seem to be validating.

So something like (untested code):

```
const link = renderedComponent.find(Link)
let result = null
link.handleClick = event => {

      const { replace, to } = link.props;

      if (replace) {
         result = null //we are expecting a push
      } else {
        result = to
      }
    }
  };
link.simulate('click')
expect(result).toEqual('/toto') // '/toto' or 'toto'?
```

### UPDATE

I've realised that the above doesn't work with a shallow render, however, if you just want to check if the `to` property is correct, you can probably just do it with `expect(link.props.to).toEqual('/toto')`.